# I want to find the patient id with disease id 1 in his nth visit and disease id 2 in his immediate next n+1 visit on the basis of date

Tags: mysql

I have a database visit containing `VisitID`, `PatientID`, `DiseaseID` and `Date`. In the screenshot below `PatientID` 58 should be present as it has `DiseaseID` 1 in its n-th visit and `DiseaseID` 2 in its immediate next n+1 visit:

[image]

But `PatientID` 92 should not be present as `DiseaseID` 2 is not present immediate next to `DiseaseID` 1 on the basis of date:

[image]

I tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT PatientID
FROM Visit
WHERE DiseaseID = 1
  AND PatientID IN (SELECT PatientID FROM Visit WHERE DiseaseID = 2)
```

Using this I got all those `PatientID` which are having both 1 and 2 `DiseaseID` but I don't know how to find the `PatientID` with `DiseaseID` 1 in its n-th visit and `DiseaseID` 2 in its immediate next n+1 visit on the basis of date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: I am new to sql. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Hello @Shivam, you tagged the sql version as mysql; but it seems that It is ms SQL Server. Please change the tag if I am right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this depending on the DB system you are using. In standard SQL try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v1.patientid
FROM visit v1, visit v2
WHERE v1.patientid = v2.patientid
  AND v1.diseaseid = 1
  AND v2.diseaseid = 2
  AND v1.date < v2.date
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM visit v3
    WHERE v3.patientid = v1.patientid
      AND v1.date < v3.date
      AND v3.date < v2.date
  )
```

The idea is to join two queries, one for visits with disease 1 and the other for disease 2 by patient and check if there was no other visit of that patient in between.